# Как реализовать поиск по сайту online.anidub.com/index.php?do=search с помощью Jsoup?

Tags: java, post, jsoup

Никак не могу реализовать поиск по [сайту](http://online.anidub.com/index.php?do=search) с помощью Jsoup. Я знаю, что нужно использовать `POST`-метод. Пытался сделать вот так:

```
Connection.Response response = 
Jsoup.connect("https://online.anidub.com/index.php?do=search")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
        .timeout(10 * 1000)
        .method(Connection.Method.POST)
        .data("story", query)
        .followRedirects(true)
        .execute();
Document doc = response.parse();
```

Но безрезультатно!!! Также пробовал заменить `story` на `searchinput`, но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Впихнуть текст в поле ввода вышло, но сам поиск не происходит. Видимо, нужно как-то симулировать нажатие кнопки

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
Document doc = getData(query);
```

...

```
private Document getdata(String title) {
    try{
        return Jsoup.connect("https://online.anidub.com/index.php?do=search")
                    .data("story", title)
                    .data("do", "search")
                    .data("subaction", "search")
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9) Gecko/2008052906 Firefox/3.0")
                    .timeout(10000).ignoreContentType(true).post();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

также рекомендую просматривать get/post запросы в консоли браузера или insomnia